# UiCollectionView containing TextFields inside UitableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a table of 10*10 which i have to adjust in my main tableview which contains other data as well. So i decided to put collection view inside my main table view cell to minimise the scrolling.

Everything has went well except when i try to enter data in the text fields of collectionview. As in this case keyboard appear and collectionview adjust it self by moving upward then when they keyboard disappear it never comes back.

[image]

The collection view moves up when i put some data in the textfield and try to horizontally scroll it. 
Any help please.

[image]

Comment: can you add screen shot of edit textfiled so can get proper idea what kind of issue you are facing ?

Comment: kindly have a look at it.

Comment: In the above image collectionView has adjust itself by moving upward and when the keyboard disappear the collectionview doesnt adjust itself back and thus remain upward.